# Mule Studio and Community Edition

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm using Mule Studio to create my integration applications and running them on the Community Edition. I'm having issues because Mule Studio is always changing the schemas. For example, I want to use mule-ftp.xsd, but it will change it to mule-ftp-ee.xsd.

Is there a way to tell Mule Studio to not user Enterprise Edition features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found how to do it. You need to install the Community Edition runtime and edit the mule-project.xml file as explained here:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Adding+Community+Runtime